# Asp.net c# GridView Sort AutoGenerateColumns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, autogeneratecolumn

i'm having trouble to be able to sort my `gridview` with the parameter `AutoGenerateColumns = false` 
The headers are not clickable and so i can't sort, although having the parameter `AllowSort = true`

Here is my gridview:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbSortColumn" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvDeslocFinal" runat="server" Height="181px" Width="1042px" OnRowDataBound="gvDeslocFinal_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvDeslocFinal_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDeslocFinal_PageIndexChanging" OnSorted="gvDeslocFinal_Sorted" AllowPaging="True">

            <Columns>
                ...
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="False" Height="30px" />

            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Height="20px" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

This are my functions:

```
     protected void gvDeslocFinal_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gvDeslocFinal.EditIndex >= 0)
                return;

            string[] values = lbSortColumn.Text.Split(' ');
            if (values[0] == e.SortExpression)
            {
                if (values[1] != null && values[1] == "ASC")
                    lbSortColumn.Text = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
                else
                    lbSortColumn.Text = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
            }
            else
            {
                lbSortColumn.Text = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
            }


        }


 protected void gvDeslocFinal_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gvDeslocFinal.EditIndex >= 0)
                return;
            BindGrid();
        }
```

Comment: i've added the code, can you help me?

Comment: Do you have a `onsort` event on the gridview?

Comment: No, but i'm not able to create it either

Comment: Add in the HTML, to your GridView: `OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting"`

Comment: and in the server code behind add: `protected void TaskGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
  { }`

Comment: I've already had, it is gvDeslocFinal_Sorting

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire HTML `GridView` element, including all it's properties.

Comment: where do you set the gridview datasource?

Comment: i'm not undrestanding youre question

Comment: How do you populate data into the GridView? Does it have a DataSourceID property? Or do you do it on the server code?

Comment: i do in the server code

Comment: So that is the problem. Please edit the question and post the entire code you are using to bind the data to the GridView, and I'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: i'm trying to edit my question but i'm having the error of to many code...

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you pasted, you don't show your Column definitions for me to confirm, but this is probably your problem:

If you set `AutoGenerateColumns=false`, then you must define your columns, and in those Column definitions you must set the SortExpression property.  E.g....

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="itemName" SortExpression="itemName"/>
    ...
</Columns>
```